# Made new tag, but misspelled it

Tags: support, tagging

On [this question I made](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540686/how-to-center-a-circle-node-on-the-terminal-payoff-value) I tried to make a new tag `istgame`, but I misspelled as `istgames`. `istgame` is the actual name of the package for LaTeX. Now I cannot remove the old tag or even make the correct tag.

Answer (score 3):

I've edited the tag to put the correct one there. Tags with no questions associated to them are removed automatically.

- [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/170190)

Comment: Hello, it’s `istgame`, not `instgame`.

Comment: @Superman Oops. Irony. Fixed.